# Place objects in a div and append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which works:

```
let clear_button = $(' <a href="#" class="small text-secondary mr-2 d-none" title="Clear"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>').click(function () {
    filter_input.val('');
    search_button.click();
    clear_button.addClass('d-none');
});
let search_button = $(' <a href="#" class="small text-secondary" title="Search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>').click(function () {
    self.search(filter_input.val()).draw();
    clear_button.removeClass('d-none');
});

$(document).keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        search_button.click();
    }
});

$('#' + settings.nTable.id + '_filter').append(clear_button, search_button);
```

However, I want to place both buttons in a div and append that.

I've tried this:

```
$('#' + settings.nTable.id + '_filter').append('<div class="table-search">', clear_button, search_button, '</div>');
```

and this:

```
let div = '<div class="table-search">' + clear_button + search_button + '</div>';
$('#' + settings.nTable.id + '_filter').append(div);
```

Neither are giving the desired result. The first doesn't seem to create the div with the buttons in it properly, and the 2nd shows object references instead of the actual html in the div.

How do I place these 2 objects in a div and then append it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you concatenate objects to strings, the objects get coerced to strings - that's not what you want, you should *pass* each object to `append` instead.

You should `append` the new elements to the tableSearch `div` and *then* append the tableSearch `div` to the outer `'#' + settings.nTable.id + '_filter'`:

```
const $tableSearch = $('<div class="table-search"></div>')
  .append(clear_button, search_button);
$('#' + settings.nTable.id + '_filter').append($tableSearch);
```

```js
let clear_button = $(' <a href="#" class="small text-secondary mr-2 d-none" title="Clear"><i class="fa fa-times">clear</i></a>').click(function() {
  console.log('clear clicked');
  filter_input.val('');
  search_button.click();
  clear_button.addClass('d-none');
});
let search_button = $(' <a href="#" class="small text-secondary" title="Search"><i class="fa fa-search">search</i></a>').click(function() {
  console.log('search clicked');
  self.search(filter_input.val()).draw();
  clear_button.removeClass('d-none');
});

$(document).keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    search_button.click();
  }
});
const $tableSearch = $('<div class="table-search"></div>')
  .append(clear_button, search_button);

$('body').append($tableSearch);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Inspect me
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the div as a jQuery object first, just like how you create the buttons. Then append the button to the div. Finally append the div to the parent.

```
$('#' + settings.nTable.id + '_filter').append($('<div class="table-search"></div>').append(clear_button,search_button))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
clear_button.add(search_button).appendTo($('<div class="table-search"></div>').appendTo($('#' + settings.nTable.id + '_filter')));
```

Live sample:

```js
$(function(){
  $("[b]").click(function(){
     $("[clear_button]").add($("[search_button]")).appendTo($('<div class="table-search"></div>').appendTo($('[dest]')));
     $("[b]").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.table-search{
    background-color: #ff0;
    position: relative;
 }
 .table-search:before{
    content:"I am yellow .table-search!";
    position:absolute;
    top:-2;
    right:0;
    font-size: 8pt;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b style='color: #090' clear_button>Clear_Button </b><br/>
<b style='color: #009' search_button>Search_Button </b><br/>
<div style='border: solid 1px #f90; min-height: 40px; min-width: 40px' dest>

</div>
<input type='button' value='Append' b/>
```